# Subscribe to multiple topics Asyncio_mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, python-asyncio

I'm trying to subscribe to multiple mqtt topics and receive all their messages at once.
This is part of my code:

```
class mqtt_task():
def __init__(self, broker, subscription):
    self.broker = broker
    self.subscription = subscription

async def sub_and_listen_task(self):
    while True:
        try:
            async with Client(self.broker) as client:
                self.client = client
                print(self.subscription)
                #for i in self.subscription:
                async with client.filtered_messages(self.subscription) as messages:
                    await client.subscribe(self.subscription)
                    async for message in messages:
                        print(message.payload, ' ' ,  message.topic)
mqtt_task(broker, subscription)
```

Self.subscription is a list of topics, using a for loop didnt work as it just subscribes to the first one. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what module do you use? I don't like `while True` in your code. Normally I would create `Client` only once andd subscribe topics only once and client would assing `callback` which will receive topics when they will be available on server.

Comment: example `advanced use` in [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/asyncio-mqtt/) shows `for`-loop which runs every topic in separated `filtered_messages` and later it runs `subscribe` with more general topic - like `"floors/#"` with `#`. And every filter runs in separated task created with `asyncio.create_task()`

Comment: @furas I did not add my full code due to it might result in confusion but in my `main` function `sub_and_listen_task` is a task. Would it be possible to subscribe to multiple topics within this `sub_and_listen_task` function? I read the docs but its quite confusing because filters do not really help my situation. Both topics I subscribe to are not related at all and a filter would not help. E.g. one topic is `window/+/+/kitchen` and the other is `living_room/#`. I appreciate your help btw

Comment: @furas I also found that for Paho-mqtt you can just subscribe by passing a list of tuples of the (topic, qos). Would that not be possible here?

Comment: you would have to test it in your code. [Source code](https://github.com/sbtinstruments/asyncio-mqtt/blob/master/asyncio_mqtt/client.py#L211) shows that `async subscribe` runs directly normal `subscribe` so it could works with list.

Comment: @furas I just tested it, subscribe takes multiple subscriptions but it is `client.filtered_messages` that I need to pass multiple topics. That is the one apparently that eventually filter to the real topics. Sadly it does not seem to accept multiple topics. Trying something like this right now but i cant find a way to receive both messages simultaneously `Async with Client("test.mosquitto.org") as client:`
       `async with client.filtered_messages("$SYS/broker/messages/stored") as messages:`
            `async with client.filtered_messages("$SYS/broker/messages/received") as messages2:`